# Regex replace one or two letter words

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace one or two letters in a string. Please consider this regex

```
$str = 'I haven\'t got much time to spend!';
echo preg_replace('/\b([a-z0-9]{1,2})\b/i','',$str);

returns: haven' got much time spend!
expected output: haven't got much time spend!
```

My goal is remove any one or two characters length words from a string. This can be alphanumeric or special characters.

Comment: What about the string `foo a, bb, bar :cc zz.`, what would the desired result be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use lookarounds:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\S)\S{1,2}(?!\S)/', '', $str)
```

Altho this leaves double whitespace when words are removed. To also remove spaces you could try something like:

```
preg_replace('/\s+\S{1,2}(?!\S)|(?<!\S)\S{1,2}\s+/', '', $str)
```

Comment: eh! we came exactly to the same solution! I think this is best, none of the other works up to now

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\S)\S{1,2}(?!\S)/i', '', 'a dljlj-b2 adl xy zq a');
```

The output is as wanted:

```
 dljlj-b2 adl
```

So don't forget to handle beginning/end of a string by negative assertions.

Comment: Beat you to it by 5 min, and no need for `/i` ;-)